# regex: get string and optional extra string in python

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for these urls with regex in a list of html pages, each page with their own unique url shown below

```
http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/sfc/apa?
http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/sfc/apa?s=100
http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/sfc/apa?s=200
http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/sfc/apa?s=300
```

I've tried this regex expression in an attempt to get the first url, as well as the following urls that have a set of strings the first does not

```
re_search = '(http\:\/\/sfbay\.craigslist\.org\/search\/sfc\/apa\?(s\=\d+)?)'
searched_urls = re.findall(re_search, str(search_page_html))
searched_urls
```

- search_page_html, is the list of html pages

It gives this result, but I only want the first result of each tuple.

```
('http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/sfc/apa?', ''),
('http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/sfc/apa?s=100', 's=100'),
('http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/sfc/apa?s=200', 's=200'),
('http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/sfc/apa?s=300', 's=300'),
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regex, a pair of parenthesis will capture a match.  You have two pairs of parenthesis, and therefore two matches in each tuple.

```
(s\=\d+)
```

is capturing the `''`, `'s=100'`, `'s=200'`, and `'s=300'`.  You can change that group to a *non* capturing group by adding `?:` to the beginning of the parenthesis, like so:

```
(?:s\=\d+)
```